# Uninstall detox completely from MacOS

Tags: node.js, npm, detox

I want to completely uninstall Detox from my Mac (`10.14.6 (18G5033)`)

I have uninstalled the global `detox-cli` with `npm uninstall -g detox-cli`

There is still a directory here `~/Library/Detox/*` with a bunch of detox images. Can these be removed manually? or is there an uninstall script or other directories that need to be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no official uninstallation process but one will be added to `detox`. Issue [2270](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2270) was opened and documentation will be added.

The process to uninstall is:

1. Remove the `detox-cli`

   ```
   npm uninstall -g detox-cli
   ```
2. Remove the support folder in `~/Library/Detox/*`

   ```
   rm -fr ~/Library/Detox/
   ```

*Detox may add an official uninstallation script at a later time*